# Need to extract information from the JSON response?

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, rest, python-requests

I have a rest endpoint giving me below response. I am using python and using `requests` and `json` library.

From the below response, i want to get **messageId** from the `lastMessage` tag.
And **list of all messages** in python list.

**JSON Response:**

```
{
   "batchResponseContext":{
      "partitionId":"0",
      "total":3,
      "batchMessages":{

            "data":{
               "sessionId":"7391",
               "xCode":"19979",
               "micode":"129879",
               "percentChange":-1.23,
               "low":844.95,
               "high":869.86,
               "ytd":0.0,
            },
            "messageProperties":{
               "LOCATION":"n8",
               "ENV":"uat"
            }
         },
         "lastMessage":{
            "data":{
               "sessionId":"7391",
               "xCode":"22144",
               "micode":"705390",
               "percentChange":0.25,
               "low":1408.93,
               "high":1414.78,
               "ytd":0.0,
            },
            "messageProperties":{
               "LOCATION":"NY",
               "ENV":"uat"
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "messages":[
      {
         "data":{
            "sessionId":"7391",
            "xCode":"19979",
            "micode":"129879",
            "percentChange":-1.23,
            "low":844.95,
            "high":869.86,
            "ytd":0.0,
          },
         "messageProperties":{
            "LOCATION":"n8",
            "ENV":"uat"
         }
      },
      {
         "data":{
            "sessionId":"7391",
            "xCode":"25719",
            "micode":"712978",
            "percentChange":-0.53,
            "low":1355.45,
            "high":1386.63,
            "ytd":0.0,
         },
         "messageProperties":{
            "LOCATION":"NY",
            "ENV":"uat"
         }
      },
      {
         "data":{
            "sessionId":"7391",
            "xCode":"22144",
            "micode":"705390",
            "percentChange":0.25,
            "low":1408.93,
            "high":1414.78,
            "ytd":0.0,
          },
         "messageProperties":{
            "LOCATION":"NY",
            "ENV":"uat"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

I have tried this until now:

```
import requests 
import json  
r = requests.get('URL') 
json_data = json.dumps(r.text, indent=2)
```

How can i get last message id and list of messages in python object?

Comment: You just need to use ```json_data = r.json()``` and it will work!

Comment: @Enrique can you give an example how i can convert this like an object?

Comment: you can use `json_data = r.json()` to get the response. Then treat it like a python dict and do somthing like `json_data["batchResponseContext"]["batchMessages"]["lastMessage"]["data"]["sessionId"]` to get the last message session id.